# How to adjust CSS grid row height using the max function?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid with 1 column and 10 rows. The cells contain text which varies in length. I want all rows to take a min-height of 100vh and exceed that size if necessary, i.e. if the content overflows.

So I have tried to use the max function like this, but I guess it cannot handle the "auto" value:

`grid-template-rows: repeat(10, max(auto, 100vh))`

The same happens when I replace auto by min-content or similar expressions.

Is there a way to get the syntax correct for the logic explained above?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: function name is `minmax` not `max`. `grid-template-rows: repeat(10, minmax(100vh, max_content));`

Comment: @Yousaf max also exist: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `grid-auto-rows:minmax(100vh,1fr)`

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-rows:minmax(100vh,1fr);
}
.container > * {
  border:2px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</div>
```

And with more content:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-rows:minmax(100vh,1fr);
}
.container > * {
  border:2px solid;
  font-size:50px;
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus iaculis felis, nec molestie augue porta et. Vestibulum condimentum, dui sed rutrum vulputate, dolor est volutpat urna, ut consequat diam purus eu justo. Quisque fringilla aliquet risus, vitae feugiat lectus venenatis nec</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus iaculis felis, nec molestie augue porta et. Vestibulum condimentum, dui sed rutrum vulputate, dolor est volutpat urna, ut consequat diam purus eu justo. Quisque fringilla aliquet risus, vitae feugiat lectus venenatis nec</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus iaculis felis, nec molestie augue porta et. Vestibulum condimentum, dui sed rutrum vulputate, dolor est volutpat urna, ut consequat diam purus eu justo. Quisque fringilla aliquet risus, vitae feugiat lectus venenatis nec</div>
</div>
```

Or like below if you don't want equal height row:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-auto-rows:minmax(100vh,max-content);
}
.container > * {
  border:2px solid;
  font-size:50px;
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus iaculis felis, nec molestie augue porta et. Vestibulum condimentum, dui sed rutrum vulputate, dolor est volutpat urna, ut consequat diam purus eu justo. Quisque fringilla aliquet risus, vitae feugiat lectus venenatis nec</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus finibus iaculis felis, nec molestie augue porta et. Vestibulum condimentum, dui sed rutrum vulputate, dolor est volutpat urna, ut consequat diam purus eu justo. Quisque fringilla aliquet risus, vitae feugiat lectus venenatis nec</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for - I went for the latter option minmax(100vh,max-content)! Thank you!